# Update ListView using Linq to Sql Classes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, listview

Im trying to do a simple program that adds data to the database through linq to sql, what im trying to achieve is when i send the data, the listview automatically update here's the behind-code

```
private DataClasses1DataContext DC = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        ListViewData.ItemsSource = DC.Persons;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        Person NewPerson = new Person() { Name = nametxt.Text, Address = addresstxt.Text };

        DC.Persons.InsertOnSubmit(NewPerson);
        DC.SubmitChanges();

    }
```

XAML code

```
<ListView Name="ListViewData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="238" Margin="10,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

i read about the  INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged but i think the code generated by Visual Studio when a Linq To Sql Class is added already implements them, but i'm not sure, i just started to use WPF

Comment: ObservableCollection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListView` will not update itself automatically when the source collection changes unless the source collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  If the source collection does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` then you will have to manually update the `ItemsSource` property.  In your case, however, I do not think you can simply do this:

```
DC.SubmitChanges();
ListViewData.ItemsSource = DC.Persons;
```

I am pretty sure (not positive) that `DC.Person` will still refer to the same object after you call `DC.SubmitChanges()`.  If you try to re-set the `ItemsSource` property to the same value it will not trigger a refresh.

If the `DC.Persons` has relatively few items then you could do this:

```
DC.SubmitChanges();
ListViewData.ItemsSource = DC.Persons.ToArray();
```

That will copy `Persons` to a new array and assign that array to the ListView's `ItemsSource` property.  If you have thousands of items then you may want to find another solution; maybe the `CollectionViewSource`.